# c++ member function argument is not used in the function body, what is this case?

Tags: c++, c++11

I see this code, it's a class member function definition. But the argument is just std::tuple<>  and it is not being used in the function body. What does this mean? (from dlib.net dlib/dnn/core.h)

```
    add_layer (         
        std::tuple<> 
    ) : add_layer() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the argument is just std::tuple<> and it is not being used in the function body.

There's nothing that `std::tuple<>` can be used for in the function body. It is an empty class.

> What does this mean?

It is a constructor. It delegates to the default constructor.

Comment: ok, but why do people write such a function definition? I guess, so that when the input argument type is anything std::tuple, it is ignored and just a default constructor is run?

Comment: @ChanKim That constructor matches only the empty tuple; no other tuple.